# Player for rtmp:// protocol?

Tags: stream

Is there a player for the rtmp:// (flash streaming) protocol?

Answer (score 6):

[VLC](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vlc)
 supports rtmp protocol. Well, VLC supports almost anything you throw at it!

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

Comment: vlc doesnt suport it! (at least for me) I tried rtmp://69.55.53.31:1935/live/ch_22 and many others

Comment: Weird, I looked it up here: http://wiki.videolan.org/Rtmp

Comment: Since this was answered, VLC has added support.  (at least, it has on the Mac version)

Answer (score 4):

Try ffplay:

```
ffplay "rtmp://planeta-online.tv:1936/live/channel_22"
ffplay "rtmp://cp97712.live.edgefcs.net/live/Air1044flash@25902"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a command line app called [flvstreamer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/flvstreamer) [image: Install flvstreamer] for streaming RTMP.

Answer (score 1):

Native Ubuntu video player "Totem" can open rtmp. Just press "ctrl+L" and add link.

Comment: This answer might be useful if you were to [edit] it and tell us which native Ubuntu video player are you referring to and  what stream  you tested  it on?

Comment: Do you mean [Totem](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/totem/)? That's the default media player of Ubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: Yes, i meant "Totem" and already edited answer. In Ubuntu with russian interface this player just called "Video" (in translation from russian). That's why its name was not obvious.