# How do I streaming rtmp?

Tags: vlc, stream

I want to stream with VLC or flvstreamer and the only method that accepts the site I need is SMTP, and the only information the server gives me is "rtmp://blablabla" and stream name. Help me, please. I don't know where should I paste these things in VLC. Alternatively, could you give examples of how to use flvstreamer?

I have VLC version 1.1.4

Comment: which version of vlc do you use?

Comment: I have vlc version 1.1.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Player for rtmp:// protocol?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8947/player-for-rtmp-protocol)

Answer (score 2):

Take erlyvideo, it is really a rtmp streaming server, vlc is not

Comment: I think vlc is also a server: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_Newhttp://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html